# Media query doesn't work in my case

Tags: html, css, sass, media-queries

i used media queries long ago.

I'm already linked the main.css file so dont worry about it

I linked this in head for first step

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Im using koala because of SASS and using this code in main.scss :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)  {
    .numet{
       margin-top:150.5px;margin-left:150px;
    }
}
```

Im calling numet class on a picture because style="" it's not an option at the moment.

```
<img class="numet" style="" src="wt.png" alt="">
```

What im trying to do here when the screen is max-width:600px for example

when im checking this project on a galaxy s5 i want the pciture go down 150.5px.

and go left 150px. BUT the PROBLEM is that it isn't working it does nothing. My css file isn't cached in the browser so it's not the problem. I searched a lot of questions here on stackoverflow but none of them was good for me so please don't mark as a duplicate.

Thanks for the help. Im here to learn :)

Comment: well, your media query looks OK (despite 150.5px not making much sense), so it's probably something else in your code. Probably how the element is being positioned on the document flow. Or the fact that the S5 has quite more than 600px width-wise. Have you actually checked it on your desktop's developer tools?

Comment: @FacundoCorradini Hi you are right something is wrong with my code actually i found the problem because of your advice i'm really glad thanks.

The problem was. I didn't start koala. Koala wasn't running so it didn't complie the code. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem was that i didn't run the Koala program which is the compiler.
So i started Koala it complied my main.scss file for main.css and now it works well.

So if you are having problem with this always check that your compiler is running. :)

@FacundoCorradini thanks for the help.